# Complex FeatureCollection bounds

Tags: google-earth-engine

Extracting a bounding box from a FeatureCollection taking longer than expected. My layer has 86 multi-polygons:

```
var inun_raw = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sbryant/fred/GeoNB_LSJ_FloodExtent2018_0515b');
print('inun_raw feats = ' + inun_raw.size().getInfo())
var bbox = inun_raw.union().geometry().bounds(1000)
```

This takes many minutes to get a simple bounding box (the same operation in QGIS takes 0.03 secs).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your collection has more than 2 million edges in it.  It's just too complex for the geometry processing system.  You would probably do best to simplify the geometries before ingesting it.